# How to allow user to touch scroll using libgdx in a cross-plattform project?

Tags: java, scroll, camera, libgdx, orthographic

I'm developing a cross-plattform application in java (focusing on android right now) and I'm mainly using libgdx to achieve this. Right now I have a screen that consists of rows of clickable buttons where the rows extend below the screen. I want to allow the user to touch/flick scroll up and down in order for them to view all the different buttons available.

Some relevant information: I'm using an Orthographic Camera and an InputProcessor.
Right now I'm thinking that the camera is supposed to move up and down based on the touchDragged method in the InputProcessor.

I'll attach the relevant code in the GameRenderer and InputHandler classes below. (with a lot of unrelevant code removed.) Any help or suggestions would be great, I've googled like a mad man and been stuck for a day now.

GameRenderer

```
public class GameRenderer {

private GameWorld myWorld;
private OrthographicCamera cam;
private SpriteBatch batcher;
private ArrayList<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();

private int gameHeight;

public GameRenderer(GameWorld world, int gameHeight) {
    myWorld = world;
    elements = myWorld.getElement();
    this.gameHeight = gameHeight;

    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(true, 136, gameHeight);

    batcher = new SpriteBatch();
    batcher.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
}

public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 191, 255, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batcher.begin();

for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
            Element e = (Element) elements.get(i);
            batcher.draw(AssetLoader.element, e.getLocationX(), e.getLocationY(), e.getElementWidth(), e.getElementHeight());
            AssetLoader.font.draw(batcher, e.getFormula(), e.getLocationX() + 4, e.getLocationY() + 3);
            }

    batcher.end();

    }

}
```

InputHandler

```
public class InputHandler implements InputProcessor 
{
private Element myElement;
private float scaleX, scaleY;
private ArrayList<Element> elements;
GameWorld myWorld;
GameRenderer myRenderer;

   public InputHandler(GameWorld game, GameRenderer renderer, ArrayList elementList, float x, float y) {

    myWorld = game;
    myRenderer = renderer;
    elements = elementList;
    scaleX = x;
    scaleY = y;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    return false;

}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried libGDX ScrollPane component? https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ScrollPane.html[/link]

Comment: I've been trying a ScrollPane solution for a couple of hours now, while I did eventually get it to scroll by always changing the .setBounds() method of the ScrollPane, it just ended up screwing up my collision-detection completely. I decided to opt out and go for an easier solution by just having one object on each page. Thanks though!